# There is a way to access and inject "on the run" values on a executable?

Tags: executable, code-injection

For example, imagine a software called chess.exe; it's a normal chess game, player vs computer.
I want to send things like a fake piece movement instead the one I've made on the game.
Or see what values the software is holding during the execution.

Comment: There is no standard way of doing this. You'd have to find a vulnerability in the software. You'd have to understand how the user input is translated into a move of your piece in the software.

Comment: Any tip? Any kind of sniffer that shows me software used information or things like that?

Comment: You could use a disassembler, depending on your level of programming expertise and on the structure of the program, it would require some training to use it. There might be easier ways, e.g. if there is a text file that contains all the moves and is read into the program again after every move, then you could just manipulate the file. (This is very unlikely and just an example). There is no general answer, I believe.

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to cheat the game :p , try this: http://www.cheatengine.org/aboutce.php, it can be used as debugger too (as cited on about page) and modifying value during the execution of the program. **Note that the antivirus will detect this program as virus**

Comment: @SebastianLanger Thank you, I am studding more about disassemblers now.

Comment: @cakil That's great! Really is what I was looking for. I am having a lot of fun with it, thank you! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Cheat Engine](http://www.cheatengine.org/) will do the best for that. It is open source and comes with a memory scanner to quickly scan for variables used within a game and allow you to change them, but it also comes with a debugger, disassembler, assembler, speedhack, trainer maker, direct 3D manipulation tools, system inspection tools and more (cited in [about](http://www.cheatengine.org/aboutce.php)). You can easily change the value during the program execution, not only for games but also other programs too.